# AWS S3 Internal Server Error: Tyring to upload pdf file on after another

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I'm trying to generate **PDF** file using **FPDF and PHP** and later upload to  **AWS-s3** and generate the **url.** When I executed the below code in my **local-machine** Using **XAMPP** it's generating files and uploading it to **S3**.

But When I deployed in **AWS server as an API** it's uploading only first file and for other its giving **500 server error**

**Below is my code that I used in Local Machine**

```
    require '../fpdf/fpdf.php';
    require 'start.php';

    use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

    $location = "bangalore";
    $db     =   getConnection();
    $query   = "SELECT first_name FROM customer_info where location = '$location'";
    $execute = $db->query($query);
    $result  = $execute->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
 $pdf = new FPDF();
 $pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 14);
$txt = "Legal Document of ".$result[$i]['first_name'];
$pdf->Cell(180, 0, $txt, 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->Line(5, 20, 200, 20);

$docname = $result[$i]['first_name'] . ".pdf";
$filepath = "../file/{$docname}";
$pdf->Output($filepath, 'F');

//s3 client
try {
       $res = $S3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $config['S3']['bucket'],
        'Key' => "PATH_TO_THE_DOCUMENT/{$docname}",
        'Body' => fopen($filepath, 'rb'),
        'ACL' => 'public-read'
    ]);

    var_dump($res["ObjectURL"]);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

}

**Output:**

```
   Array ( [0] => Array ( [first_name] => Mohan ) [1] => Array ( [first_name] => Prem ) [2] => Array ( [first_name] => vikash ) [3] => Array ( [first_name] => kaushik ) )

     string(70) "https://streetsmartb2.s3.amazonaws.com/PATH_TO_THE FILE/Mohan.pdf" 

 string(72) "https://streetsmartb2.s3.amazonaws.com/PATH_TO_THE FILE/Prem%20.pdf"
```

**API CODE**

```
      //pdf generation another api
      $app->post('/pdfmail', function() use($app){

    //post parameters
    $location = $app->request->post('loc');
    $id       = $app->request->post('id');



   $db = getConnection();
   $query   = "SELECT * FROM customer_info where location = '$location'";
  $execute = $db->query($query);
  $result  = $execute->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $len = sizeof($result);

  //request array
  $request = array();

  if($result != Null) {
      for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
          $pdf = new FPDF();
          $pdf->AddPage();

          $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 14);
          $txt = "Document of Mr." . $result[$i]['first_name'];
          $pdf->Cell(180, 0, $txt, 0, 1, 'C');
          $pdf->Line(5, 20, 200, 20);

          $docname = $result[$i]['first_name'] . ".pdf";
          var_dump($docname);
          $filepath = "../file/{$docname}";
          var_dump($filepath);
          $pdf->Output($filepath, 'F');


          //s3 client
          require '../aws/aws-autoloader.php';

          $config = require('config.php');


          //create s3 instance
          $S3 = S3Client::factory([
              'version' => 'latest',
              'region' => 'REGION',
              'credentials' => array(
                  'key' => $config['S3']['key'],
                  'secret' => $config['S3']['secret']
              )
          ]);



          try {
              $res = $S3->putObject([
                  'Bucket' => $config['S3']['bucket'],
                  'Key' => "PATH_TO_FILE{$docname}",
                  'Body' => fopen($filepath, 'rb'),
                  'ACL' => 'public-read'
              ]);
              var_dump($res["ObjectURL"]);
          } catch (S3Exception $e) {
              echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
          }

      }
  }
```

**OUTPUT WHEN TESTED IN POSTMAN**

```
    string(10) "vikash.pdf"
    string(18) "../file/vikash.pdf"
   string(71) "https://streetsmartb2.s3.amazonaws.com/PATH_TO_FILE/vikash.pdf"
  string(13) "pradeepan.pdf"
   string(21) "../file/pradeepan.pdf"
```

**After this I'm getting internal server error.**

Comment: Can you also share that internal error exception ?

Comment: To see the _actual_ error message instead of the generic "internal server error", check your servers error log. Without that, we would just be guessing.

Comment: @smilyface,@Magnus Eriksson...Sry bros...I dont have complete access to aws...Is their any server execution time in aws..Like we have in XAMPP..??

Comment: @pradeepSharma they are talking about *your* server log, not S3.  Is "Internal Server Error" the contents of `$e->getMessage()` or is that the response you get from this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of using require_once I've use require...So as the code traversed it was creating AWS Class again and again.**

**Code**

```
      //s3 client
      require '../aws/aws-autoloader.php'; //use require_once

      $config = require('config.php');


      //create s3 instance
      $S3 = S3Client::factory([
          'version' => 'latest',
          'region' => 'REGION',
          'credentials' => array(
              'key' => $config['S3']['key'],
              'secret' => $config['S3']['secret']
          )
      ]);
```